# How can I make my page responsive with a scroll instead of having everything go squishy?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my page automatically go to scroll when the window is at a small height instead of trying to adjust to the height by getting squishy. I've tried different ways of using overflow, but I can't seem to find a way to make it scroll the page as a whole no matter where I put it. The codepen is here: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/aubry-villaver-bratcher/pen/mdPmXzv) Thank you in advance!

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oleo+Script&display=swap');


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

a {
    color: #8524C6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #F5D0E4, #F6D5F2, #EAD5F6, #D9D5F6, #D5E1F6, #D5ECF6);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    position: relative;
    animation: change 10s ease-in-out infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
} 

h1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive, 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .07rem;
    transform: translateY(15vh);
}

h1 span {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

h1:hover span {
    animation: animate .5s infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0)
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-30px)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0)
    }
}

h1 span:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
h1 span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: .1s;
}
h1 span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: .2s;
}

h2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #000;
    font-size: .4rem;
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive, serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transform: translateY(15.5vh)
}

.dancing-hamsters {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.3rem;
    width: 5.1rem;
    transform: translateY(18vh);
    z-index: 1;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    align-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 3%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
}


.top-note {
    /* display: flex; */
    display: none;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size: .65rem;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #000;
    transform: translate(4%, -5%);
}



.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive, serif;
    font-size: .5rem;
    margin: 2rem;
}

img {   
    display: flex;
    width: 85%;
    height: 75%;
}

.container img {
    cursor: url('https://i.postimg.cc/6338xsj2/oie-nr-M8-Ct-Mr-SPb-H.png'), auto;
}

.box-text {
    margin-top: 10%;
    cursor: url('https://i.postimg.cc/6338xsj2/oie-nr-M8-Ct-Mr-SPb-H.png'), auto;
}

.nav {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(70vh);
    font-size: .5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: .8rem;
}

.nav a {
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive, serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #8524C6;
}


footer {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1rem;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: .75rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateY(80vh);
}

@keyframes change {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 50%;
    }
}

/* Media Queries */

@media screen and (min-width: 740px) {

    h1 {
        font-size: 3em;
        transform: translateY(8vh);
        word-spacing: 2em;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 1rem;
        transform: translateY(8vh);
    }

    .dancing-hamsters {
        height: 2rem;
        width: 9rem;
        transform: translateY(10.5vh);
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        }

    .top-note {
        display: none;
    }

    .box {
        width: 15rem;
        height: 15rem;
        transform: translateX(15%);
        font-size: .75rem;
       }
    
    .img {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
        }

    .nav li {
            margin: .5em;
            display: inline;
            text-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-size: .85rem;
            }
    .nav {
        transform: translateY(64vh);
    }

    footer {
        transform: translateY(75vh);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want flexbox. It can be used to control the flow of a webpage in the way you're describing. Read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution will be to add `min-height` to the main `section` element:

```
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 500px; // I just add 500px for demo
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #F5D0E4, #F6D5F2, #EAD5F6, #D9D5F6, #D5E1F6, #D5ECF6);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    position: relative;
    animation: change 10s ease-in-out infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

You have specified the height of the section, but with `min-height` you will guarantee that regardless of the screen height, your content will not get smaller than what you have set.

Comment: Magical. Thank you!